# When a list of categories becomes available in store A, select one category and set its ID in store B

Tags: react-alt

I have two stores - GroupsStore and ItemsFilterStore. The ItemsFilterStore's state should contain a choice of a single Group from the groups available in the GroupsStore, but:

- the groups are not initially available in the GroupsStore, so the choice in the ItemsFilterStore cannot initially be made (the constructor initializes it to null).
- once the groups become available in the GroupStore, I need to perform an action that will select one group (according to some logic) and set its ID in the ItemsFilterStore.

**THE PROBLEM:**

I read **EVERYWHERE** that triggering actions from action handlers in a store is an antipattern.

So how do I engineer this correctly?

Comment: I had a hard time figuring out the similar issue myself. Can you, pls, give a little more info, how do you populate the GroupsStore? As i understand, initially it's empty, what happens next? Is the ajax request triggered by an action from the view or where does it get the data?

Comment: The ajax request is triggered by an action called in the search filter UI's componentDidMount(). Since I am using sources, I don't get the ajax promise - the sources mechanism hides it from me. Besides, stores should not know about each other, and this principle would forbid fiddling with another store inside the body of the first store's resultsReceived() handler.

This is where alt fails. It forbids designed-in dependencies between stores, and it rigs the rules so that expressing such dependencies in code external to stores is impossible.

In the end I just decided to violate a rule.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came up with 2 possible ways of handling this case. Just for the clarity, let's say you have an action `getGroups` that fires the request to the source. When the request is successful it fires the action `resultsRecieved`, which `GroupsStore` handles.

1) You can listen to the `resultsRecieved` action in both stores and handle the results to update the `ItemsFilterStore`. But in that case you might need to pull out the group selection logic from `GroupsStore` into some utility file, that can be imported and used in both stores, if this is possible.

2) You can listen to the `getGroups` action in both stores. In the `ItemsFilterStore` handler for that action you can utilise Alt's [wait-for](http://alt.js.org/guide/wait-for/) method which signals that this store depends on another store for its data and should wait for it to be updated. So the getGroups handler in `ItemsFilterStore`  might look something like this in the end:

```
getGroups() {
    this.waitFor(GroupsStore);
    var groups = GroupsStore.getState().groups;
}
```

I am not fully sure how good wait for will work with the async source requests, since I only used it to wait for synchronous operations.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but I can already say that method 2 probably won't work, because it will only wait for GroupsStore to complete its getGroups() action handler. After `this.waitFor(GroupsStore);` line we can only be sure that the `GroupsStore` initiated the ajax request, not that the request has completed and the results are available.

As to method 1) I'll try it and report results. For some reason I mistakenly believed that ItemsFilterStore would be honor killed if it went dancing with another store's Actions (probably because no examples on the alt website ever do this).

Comment: And i havent thought of that before, but probably you can even use a wait for inside ```resultsRecieved``` handler to wait for the update inside GroupsStore and use it's data.